# Disable Control-Alt-D in window manager

Tags: keyboard, lxde

It is taken by the window manager to minimise all windows. I need that shortcut for my own application. I don't find it:

```
cat /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml | grep C-A-
```

Does not list anything bound to Control-Alt-D. I does have `W-d` which is bound to `ToggleShowDesktop`. I also don't have custom settings (`~/.config/openbox` does not exist). Where is that shortcut defined, and how can I disable it? Raspbian Stretch.

I tried removing the `W-d` binding; I also tried copying the file to `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` and adding empty entries for `C-A-d` and `W-d`, no success, the action is still executed.

Comment: `/cat/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` is that an existing file? I would have thought it's `/etc/xdg/`etcetera

Comment: @Dirk oops, sorry, corrected